# How do I solve the Razor Pages error "CS0103 The name 'Json' does not exist in the current context"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, razor-pages

I am using Razor Pages (not MVC) and keep getting the above error on the return statement. There is a similar question out there relating to the MVC model but the answer to that one is to change the class to "Controller". When I try that, page related things break. Any suggestions?

```
public class VehicleInfoPageModel : PageModel
{        
    public SelectList ModelNameSL { get; set; }

public JsonResult PopulateModelDropDownList(StockBook.Models.StockBookContext _context,
        int selectedMakeID,
        object selectedModelID = null)
    {
        var ModelIDsQuery = from m in _context.VehicleModel
                            orderby m.ModelID // Sort by ID.
                            where m.MakeID == selectedMakeID
                            select m;

        ModelNameSL = new SelectList(ModelIDsQuery.AsNoTracking(),
                    "ModelID", "ModelName", selectedModelID);
        return Json(ModelNameSL);
    }
```

Comment: Returning JSON is for an MVC/Web API application, not for a Razor Pages one, so it doesn't have a `Json` helper function. Just use `return new JsonResult(ModelNameSL);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're tried to use `Json()` method which derived from either [`System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.json?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Controller_Json_System_Object_) or [`System.Web.Http.ApiController.JsonResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http.apicontroller.json?view=aspnetcore-2.1) instead of [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.jsonresult?view=aspnetcore-2.1) namespace, they're all different namespaces. You should use the constructor of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonResult` to create JSON string instead:

```
public JsonResult PopulateModelDropDownList(StockBook.Models.StockBookContext _context, int selectedMakeID, object selectedModelID = null)
{
    var ModelIDsQuery = from m in _context.VehicleModel
                        orderby m.ModelID // Sort by ID.
                        where m.MakeID == selectedMakeID
                        select m;

    ModelNameSL = new SelectList(ModelIDsQuery.AsNoTracking(),
                "ModelID", "ModelName", selectedModelID);

    // return JSON string
    return new JsonResult(ModelNameSL);
}
```

Reference: [Working With JSON in Razor Pages](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/318/working-with-json-in-razor-pages)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! This solved the problem.